# SQL Count syntax

Tags: sql, syntax, count

I have a table in which the results for members diving results are listed. I need to come up with a table that only shows individuals who have passed the diving test the first time, and include their qualification in the final table.

My logic goes that I remove anyone who has had a fail in their test-taking history and those who appear in the list more then once.

This is what I have so far. I am really new to SQL so I'm really sorry if it looks all wrong.

Thanks

```
SELECT b.branchmarina AS "Branch Suburb", m1.memsurname AS "Member Surname",      m1.memfirstname AS "Member First Name", m2.memsurname AS "Mentor Surname", m2.memfirstname     
AS "Mentor First Name", dt.dttestdate AS "Date", dt.DtQualLevel AS "Qualification" /*list of members who passed diving test on first attempt*/
FROM d_branch b, d_divetest dt, d_member m1, d_member m2
WHERE UPPER (dt.dttestresult)='PASS'
AND COUNT(DtMemberNo)<2
AND m2.MemMentorMemberNo=m1.memberno
AND m1.membranchno=b.branchno
AND dt.testresult = (SELECT *
FROM d_divetest dt1
WHERE UPPER (dt1.dttestresult)='PASS'
AND NOT EXISTS (UPPER (dt1.dttestresult)='FAIL'))
```

This is the table I'm using:

```
DtTestDate  DtMemberNo  DtQualLevel DtTestResult    DtReasonFailed
17-Apr-13   201         Beginner    Pass    
18-Apr-13   202         Advanced    Pass    
19-Apr-13   203         Expert      Pass    
20-Apr-13   204         Beginner    Pass    
21-Apr-13   205         Beginner    Fail    Not able to stabilise
26-Apr-13   205         Beginner    Pass    
22-Apr-13   206         Beginner    Fail    Not able to stabilise
27-Apr-13   206         Beginner    Fail    Not able to stabilise
27-May-13   206         Beginner    Pass    
27-Aug-13   206         Advanced    Pass    
23-Apr-13   207         Expert      Pass    
24-Apr-13   208         Beginner    Pass    
25-Apr-13   209         Advanced    Pass    
01-Dec-13   211         Beginner                                             
02-Dec-13   212         Beginner        
03-Dec-13   213         Beginner        
04-Dec-13   214         Beginner        
05-Dec-13   215         Beginner        
27-Apr-13   226         Beginner    Fail    Weight belt not secured correctly
29-Apr-13   227         Advanced    Fail    Unable to complete test
30-Apr-13   228         Beginner    Fail    Not able to stabilise
```

If anyone has any good tutorials or suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Comment: you should specify your joins in your `FROM` statement not in the `WHERE` clause [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213235(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: How do you join the member table with d_divetest?

Answer (score 0):

Change this to fit your needs:

```
SELECT b.branchmarina  AS "Branch Suburb",
       m1.memsurname   AS "Member Surname",
       m1.memfirstname AS "Member First Name",
       m2.memsurname   AS "Mentor Surname",
       m2.memfirstname AS "Mentor First Name",
       dt.dttestdate   AS "Date",
       dt.DtQualLevel  AS "Qualification" /*list of members who passed diving test on first attempt*/
FROM 
    d_branch b
INNER JOIN 
    d_member m1
ON 
    m1.membranchno = b.branchno
INNER JOIN 
    d_member m2
ON
    m2.MemMentorMemberNo = m1.memberno
INNER JOIN 
    d_divetest dt
ON 
    m2.memberno = dt.dtMemberNo
WHERE UPPER(dt.dttestresult) = 'PASS'
   AND (select count(*) from d_divetest dd where dd.dtMemberNo = dt.MemberNo)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT b.branchmarina AS "Branch Suburb",
  m1.memsurname AS "Member Surname",
  m1.memfirstname AS "Member First Name",
  m2.memsurname AS "Mentor Surname",
  m2.memfirstname AS "Mentor First Name",
  dt.dttestdate AS "Date",
  dt.DtQualLevel AS "Qualification"
FROM d_branch b
INNER JOIN d_member m1 ON m1.membranchno = b.branchno
INNER JOIN d_member m2 ON m1.MemMentorMemberNo = m2.memberno
INNER JOIN d_divetest dt ON dt.MemberNo = m1.membranchno
WHERE UPPER(dt.testresult) = 'PASS'
HAVING COUNT(dt.MemberNo) < 2;
```

This will make sure you only have one result in d_divetest  and it is 'PASS' and the rest of the JOINS is to give you the information about the branches and members involved.

**Side Note:** You can't use `COUNT(DtMemberNo)<2`  in the WHERE clause. You have to validate that in the HAVING clause.